# Scala : Expression of Type None. Type doesn't confirm to expect type Document

Tags: scala, either

I am new to Scala coding. I have below code snippet which builds document using documentBuilder. My input is XML. Whenever I input an malformed XML below code is failing to `parse` and raising SAXException.

```
def parse_xml(xmlString: String)(implicit invocationTs: Date) : Either [None, Document] = {
 try {
   println(s"Parse xmlString invoked")
   val document = documentBuilder(false).parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)))
   document.getDocumentElement.normalize()
   //Right(document)
   document
 } catch {
   case e: Exception => None
```

SAXException is raised because of the inbuilt implementation of parse function. Please see below code where SAXException is being handled:

```
public abstract Document parse(InputSource is)
    throws SAXException, IOException;
```

Now I am trying to bypass this SAXException as I don't want my job to failed just because of one malformed XML. So I have put try catch block handling below exception :

```
case e: Exception => None
```

But it's showing error here as "Expression of Type None. Type doesn't confirm to expect type Document" as my return type is document.

How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: Note that `Either[None, ...]` seems quite un-idiomatic. Why not just use `Option`?

Comment: A good solution is to return `Option[Document]` rather than `Either[None, Document]` and return `Some(document)` rather than just `document`. There are lots of good answers on this site that explain how to use `Option` effectively. If you want to preserve the exception you could return `Try[Document]`, replace the `try {` with `Try{` and remove the `catch` clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My issue solved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use wrappers, like `Either` or `Option` you always have to wrap returned value.

In case you want to pass exception further, better choice than `Either` might be `Try`:

```
def parse_xml(xmlString: String)(implicit invocationTs: Date) : Try[Document] = {
    try {
      println(s"Parse xmlString invoked")
      val document = documentBuilder(false).parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)))
      document.getDocumentElement.normalize()
      Success(document)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => Failure(e)
    }
}
```

You could even simplify it by wrapping block inside `Try.apply`:

```
Try{
   println(s"Parse xmlString invoked")
   val document = documentBuilder(false).parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)))
   document.getDocumentElement.normalize()
   document
}
```

If you don't care about exception, just about result, use `Option`:

```
def parse_xml(xmlString: String)(implicit invocationTs: Date) : Option[Document] = {
     try {
       println(s"Parse xmlString invoked")
       val document = documentBuilder(false).parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)))
       document.getDocumentElement.normalize()
       Some(document)
     } catch {
       case e: Exception => None
     }
}
```